# Node Traversal to Java String Set?

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, traversal

So I am having trouble how I would convert a nodeTraversal into Hashset.

`GraphTraversal<vertex, vertex>nodeTraversal = this.central.V().has(nodeid).in("node").values(nodeId);`

So far I have: `GraphTraverl<vertex, vertex>nodeTraversal` that returns the values of ids. I want to then convert that to a set by doing `.toSet()`, but get a `cannot convert set<Object> to set<String>`. I try to add a `.join(',')` like the tinkerpop docs but not luck.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is just an issue with getting the generics right. You've created `nodeTraversal` with `<Vertex, Vertex>` but that's technically not what you're returning. the outgoing object from `nodeTraversal` (i.e. the second `Vertex` generic definition) is not a `Vertex` but the data type of whatever the property given to `values()` is. Let's assume it was a `String`. Your code would look like:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, String> nodeTraversal = g.V().has("x").in("node").values("y");
Set<String> ids = nodeTraversal.toSet();
```